# Django queryset getting the related field name to filter an aggregate sum

Tags: django, django-queryset

In my models.py I have the following example:

```
**Orders**
id
product
total_gross


**Payments**
id
status
order_ID
```

I am creating the following queryset to get a total sum if the payment status is confirmed. So I use the following:

```
week_order_total = Order.objects.prefetch_related('payments').filter(created__range=(week_start_date, week_end_date)).filter(payments.status='confirmed').aggregate(Sum('total_gross'))['total_gross__sum']
```

I receive the following error:

> keyword can't be an expression

Comment: payments.status

Answer (score 2):

The filtering `payments.status` is not valid. You can filter on a related model with by using two consecutive underscores (`__`):

```
week_order_total = Orders.objects.filter(
    created__range=(week_start_date, week_end_date),
    payments__status='confirmed'
).aggregate(Sum('total_gross'))['total_gross__sum']
```

Using [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does not make much sense, since `.prefetch_related` only works if you obtain `Orders` objects here, and want to access the related objects at the Django/Python level. But here you aggregate at the database, so then Django will move the aggregation in an SQL query.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Order` instead of <s>`Orders`</s>.